# Compilation error after adding extent report dependency

Tags: testng, extentreports, extent

When I tried to run the testng project using maven this error showed up.. All i did was add the extent report dependency in my pom file. It works great locally where I have JAVA version 1.8..

So question does extent reports have a dependency on JAVA 1.8? and it doesnt work with JAVA version 1.8

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default)
>   on project : Execution default of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed:
>   There was an error in the forked process
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/relevantcodes/extentreports/ExtentReports : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
>     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     at
>   commbank.ui.automation.common.ExtentReporterNGListener.generateReport(ExtentReporterNGListener.java:28)
>     at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1106)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1065)   at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
>   [09:28:07][Step 1/1] Step Maven failed

Answer (score 1):

According to the [README](https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java) of the project:

> Current Version: 3.0.1
>
> Java8 only. Java7 and lower versions, use Extent v2.

So, if your target platform is Java8, use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead, use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>{latest 2.x version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But 2.41.2 (the current lastest) has a build issue: https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/678 then use a previous version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am actually using this dependency in pom <dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I updated my response. 2.41.2 has a build issue (https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports-java/issues/678). Use a previous version